# using a package locally with hex.pm

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to use a local mix project as a hex dependency?

With Bundler I could add a line like:

```
gem 'action_subscriber', :path => "../action_subscriber"
```

so that I could try out using the gem before I published a new version.  Is this possible with the hex dependency management tool?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes it is. In your `mix.exs`, you can list the dependency with the `:path` keyword (very similarly to what you do with gems).

```
def dependencies do
  [{:testing_dep, path: "/Users/me/testing_dep"}]
end
```

You can read a list of all the supported options (e.g., pulling the dependency from GitHub or from a Git repository) in the [documentation for the `mix deps` task](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html).

Comment: That documentation link is exactly what I wax looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Direct git syntax is (from the linked docs): `[{:foobar, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/foobar.git", tag: "0.1"}]`, especially useful for forks that have not yet been merged to their projects. Don't forget to do `mix deps.update --all` afterwards and you are done!